Exception in CronetUrlRequest in Kotlin program
this code (url is legit, I can copy it and post it in browser or postman and works fine).
       //in the main activity the cronet engine is set via
       cronetEngine = org.chromium.net.CronetEngine.Builder(this).build()
       ....later in the fragment the following is ran
       val executor: Executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
       val requestBuilder = cronetEngine.newUrlRequestBuilder(
            url,
            callback,
            executor
        )

        val request: UrlRequest = requestBuilder.build()
        request.start()

is returning this error
Exception in CronetUrlRequest: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, ErrorCode=1, InternalErrorCode=-105, Retryable=false, urlResponseInfo: null
